# How to hide email recipients without BCC/spam

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention

Silly question, but I have emails that I want to send to several people at once. But I don't want the recipients to see who is included in the email, as the material is somewhat sensitive.

However, when I use BCC, my emails keep ending up in their spam inbox.

Is there a way to hide email recipients without using BCC?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

Either you use BCC or you send seperate emails, these are the only two ways to prevent recipients from seeing the other recipients.

There are no other ways, no other options.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the BCC option with several mail recipients and never had this issue; there are some things to consider.

1. If you have Distribution List, try using that instead of single mail
   address as many spam filters flag emails with too many recipients in
   BCC field.
2. If you are sending the same information to different group of users,
   in this case you might want to stagger this delivery. Send one
   ground, wait some time, and send another batch as Spam filters
   detect that the same information being sent over and over to
   different recipients is a symptom of spamming.
3. Check for attachment as well, many cases spam filter detect when a
   attachment has a link, QR code a macros enabled files all this can
   trigger a spam alert..
   Lastly you can use a tool like [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) to check if your IP Address is blacklisted.

Hope this helps.